# Updating UI on a UWP (Raspberry Pi / Windows Iot)

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, windowsiot

I'm building a C# UWP program (using MvvMLight framework) to run on a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 Iot.

I have a method which downloads data from a SQL database via a WCF connection, I can see from debugging the WCF service is working, and the data downloads.

I'm puzzled why I can call this method two different ways, one updates the UI, one doesn't. Please can anyone explain why?

```
public class TagRegStep2ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<EmployeeName> _Employees;
    private string _OnScreenInstructions;
    public AsyncRelayCommand StartWizardCommand { get; private set; }

    public TagRegStep2ViewModel()
    {
        // Initialise Messenger            
        Messenger.Default.Register<InitialiseStepMessage>(this, (msg) => InitialiseStep(msg.Step));
        // Initialise Commands
        StartWizardCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(() => GetData(), () => true);
        //Set dummy default value
        OnScreenInstructions = "Default Value";
    }

    // I can see data is downloaded from WCF service and the ObservableCollection updates, but this isn't reflected in the UI.
    public void InitialiseStep(ViewModelBase vm) 
    {
        if (vm.GetType() == this.GetType())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("InitialiseStep() called");
            StartWizardCommand.TryExecute();
        }
    }

    // Method that retrieves data from WCF service. 
    // When called from a relay command, it updates the ObservableCollection and UI. 
    // When called from a MessengerCommand it updates the ObservableCollection but not the UI. Why??? 
    public async Task GetData()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Getting data...");

        OnScreenInstructions = "Loading Employees";
        await Task.Delay(25);

        var emps = await LoadEmployees(); //not posted this method, but it works
        Employees = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeName>(emps);

        OnScreenInstructions = "Please select an employee.";
        await Task.Delay(25);

        Debug.WriteLine("ObservableCollection Count :" + Employees.Count);

    }

    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeName> Employees
    {
        get { return _Employees; }
        set { Set(() => Employees, ref _Employees, value); }
    }

    public string OnScreenInstructions
    {
        get { return _OnScreenInstructions; }
        set { Set(() => OnScreenInstructions, ref _OnScreenInstructions, value); }
    }
 }
```

Comment: MvvmLight only contains a `RelayCommand`, so can you share your implementation of `AsyncRelayCommand`? Also, please share the XAML with the binding you are using for this!

Comment: The AsyncRelayCommand comes from a Nuget extension "MyToolkit".

Comment: I don't think the XAML is an issue, it works just fine when called from the AsyncRelayCommand, For brevity, I've omitted the ItemPanelTemplate and ItemTemplate:                                                                                                 `<ListView Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="300" Background="Azure" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />)`

Comment: Do you have the same issue on desktop?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.